# JQuery to make an item have a Shadow

Tags: jquery

The jquery to make an item have a Shadow (http://syddev.com/jquery.shadow/) doesn't seem to be working. This is what I have tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.shadow.css">       
<script src="jquery.shadow.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#SHADDOW').shadow({type:'sides', sides:'vt-2'});
</script>

<tr>
    <td><a href="http://burdu976.com/" id="SHADDOW" target='_blank'><img src="Photography8.png" id="SHADDOW" width="700"class="lazy" height="525" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should read the "getting started with jQuery" documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: User, use firebug to check and see if your paths are right and you are actually loading your JS files. Just a suggestion

Comment: Include jQuery first and post the errors you get with your code

Answer (score 6):

The item doesn't exist in the DOM when the script is executed, wrap the code in a `document.ready` handler so that the DOM is loaded when the code is called.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#SHADDOW').shadow({type:'sides', sides:'vt-2'});
});
```

Also, the plugin needs to be included after jQuery has been included:

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.shadow.js"></script>
```

Be sure to check that the path to the included files is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you are including `jquery.shadow.js`

And you load them in the wrong order too... it should be:

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.shadow.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.shadow.css">
```

in addition to the fix that @zzzzBov mentions in his answer.

EDIT: Looks like @Eskimo edited the original question and it now includes `jquery.shadow.js`.  I don't know if that edit to the original question is correct, as the OP might not know to include that JS file.

Comment: The raw markdown had the reference, it was poorly formatted, which hid it from being displayed properly.

Comment: @zzzzBov - I stand corrected.  Wow, that was some truly poor formatting. :)  However, the issue about order still stands.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the script files locally or using some other website to call the .js files? It seems like you are storing them locally right now.